# c# iText7 - interate throuh pdf images and change size and dpi

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a lot of very large PDF files, which contains huge images (scans).
The goal is to open PDF , read all images , change dpi, resolution and compress it.

How to managed it with Itex7?
And generally ho to iterate through all images in PDF?

```
using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader pdfReader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(inputPdfFile))
{
    using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(pdfReader))
    {
        //??
        //foreach (var image in pdfDocumentImagesList)
        //{
            //  //image.SetNewDPI()                 
        //}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**How to go through all the PDF's images?**

https://github.com/itext/i7js-book/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/book/part4/chapter15/Listing_15_30_ExtractImages.java
https://github.com/itext/i7js-book/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/book/part4/chapter15/Listing_15_31_MyImageRenderListener.java

**How to change the image's dpi and resolution?**

That's not a part of iText functionality, since iText is a PDF- rather than an image-proccessing library. I advise you to process the extracted images with some other tools and then either put them into a new document or replace the image in the PDF. The latter is not very easy. Probably the next SO answer would shed some light on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580912/pdf-convert-to-black-and-white-pngs
(its code, but in iText7: https://github.com/itext/i7js-examples/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/images/ReplaceImage.java)

**How to compress an image?**

https://github.com/itext/i7js-book/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/book/part3/chapter10/Listing_10_12_CompressImage.java

Hope that would be useful!

Comment: hi, 
thanks for short answer, but your examples are in java, Itex7 and c# are not exactly the same (not all methods are implemented)

Comment: Unfortunately these samples haven't been ported to C#. However, the API is just the same (or at least it should be). Usually it's just enough to  use meThOdNames with MeThOdNames.

Comment: It's rare with itext, for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54936031/itext7-c-sharp-net-core-extract-images-from-pdf-document
There is showed how use PdfReader and NumberOfPages attribute, but isn't implemented at all (is not present in the PdfReader class)
there is a lot of calling (methods attribiutes which are not supported right now)
Therfore I ask for straight example :)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not get you. iText7 is different from iText5, that goes without saying. iText7's PdfDocument and PdfReader differ from iText5's ones, but there is no difference in API between iText7 Java and iText7 .Net versions. 

From the question's description I get the you want to have an iText7 solution. So what's the probem then?:)

Comment: For example, to get the number of pages in iText7 Java one can call PdfDocument#getNumberOfPages() and in iText7 .Net - PdfDocument#GetNumberOfPages()

Comment: So simpy saying show me please :), the simplest code, having pdfDocument object, how to retrive list of images ( with itex7)

Comment: The only thing you need is to port the sample mentioned in my answer (Listing_15_30_ExtractImages.java) to .Net.
I'm not inclined to do it for yourself, however I can assist you if you have some specific question)