# Differentiate between blank page VS X-Cross page in PDF file Using iText7 C#

Tags: c#, itext7

I am splitting a PDF document into multiple PDF documents using IText7. For example, I have a PDF document that contains multiple combinations of pages.

- Page 1- Page with X-Cross symbol
- Page 2- Blank Page
- Page 3- Page with Text
- Page 4- Page with X-Cross symbol
- Page 5- Blank Page
- Page 6- Page with Text
- Page 7- Page with X-Cross symbol

when I tried to read the text of the page details, Page 1 & 2 both are returning the text as empty.

My question is: how could I determine the blank page and page with the X-Cross symbol? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is that X-Cross drawn? Depending on that you have to look for different items on the page.

Comment: You could think like a symbol( drawn like a Canvas). When I am trying to read the text from the page. It is returning empty which is expected. On that page, except for the X-Cross symbol, nothing is there. How to determine that page when compared to the white page(Blank page)?

Comment: I mean, how is it drawn technically? Is it drawn using pdf vector graphics? Is it an embedded bitmap? And how blank are the blank pages? Is really nothing drawn on them? Or could there be just the same cross drawn outside the visible page area? Or in white? Or covered by a white rectangle?

Comment: @mkl: It's a bitmap image embedded in one page of the PDF. The blank page means nothing drawn here(just a white pdf page)

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you explained that the *X-Cross symbol* is actually a *bitmap image*. Thus, to check whether there is such a symbol on a page, you have to apply *bitmap image extraction*, not *text extraction*. There are a number of questions and answers on bitmap image extraction on stack overflow, for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54990924/1729265) by Alexey Subach who is on the iText 7 development team.

If you are lucky, the blank pages really are *blank* (and don't contain e.g. a purely white or purely transparent bitmap image). In that case you only need to check whether or not a page has (a) any text (which you already check) and whether or not it has (b) any bitmap:

- If it has neither, it is a *Blank Page*.
- If it has only an image, it is a *Page with X-Cross symbol*.
- If it has text, it is a *Page with Text*.

If things are more complicated, you'll have to look more closely, e.g. analyze the bitmaps found on a page. If all those X-Cross symbol bitmaps are identical, you may for example compare found bitmap images with an example one you extracted first.